# Using the go trace tool with gocryptfs

Tags: go, trace, fuse

I complied [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs) from source  and I wanted to use the trace tool. So I followed https://making.pusher.com/go-tool-trace/ and added the following lines of code in the main function:

```
func main() {
    f, er := os.Create("trace.out")
    if er != nil {
            panic(er)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    er = trace.Start(f)
    if er != nil {
            panic(er)
    }
    defer trace.Stop()

    mxp := runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)
// rest of the function
}
```

I recompile via `./build-without-openssl.bash`. When I run the trace tool, I get the following error:

```
2023/01/31 14:36:24 Parsing trace...
failed to parse trace: trace is empty
```

Any pointers to what's going wrong here, or if there's another blog I can follow?

Comment: Is it really empty? I mean, what size is `trace.out`? Also: what actually is `main`? What is its connection to gocryptfs`?